# Android RxJava combine nested custom list in a single list

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

hierarchy

> `List<Job>  myJob;` // consider both list as not empty
>
> > `List<Tasks> myTasks = myJob.getTasks();`

I am using below code as of now

```
  Observable.just(myJob)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                    .concatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
                    .subscribe(new DefaultObserver<Job>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onNext(@NonNull Job myJob) {
                            Log.d(Utils.APP_LOG,
                                    "Total Task: \n " +
                                     "Job id-" + myJob.getJobId()
                                     + "tasks-" + myJob.getTasks().size());

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {

                        }
                    });
```

I am able to get parent(myJob) list and child(task) list. Now I want to combine every job's task list in a single list.

I tried to perform queries using [This accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28887010/4647628) but in my scenario job(parent) list size and task(child) list size both are dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Single<List<Tasks>> taskObservable = Observable.fromIterable(myJob)
            .flatMapIterable(Job::getTasks)
            .toList();
```

The above code will do the following:

1. Take your list of jobs and transform it into a stream that emits `Job`s
2. for every job, transform it into a stream that emits `Tasks`
3. Collect all emitted Tasks into a single list and emit that `List`

Comment: Exactly what I asked. Just did minor change `.toList()` returns `Single` interface. `Single<List<TaskModel>> taskObservable;`

Comment: oh you're right I forgot about `Single`; I'll update the answer for the next person

Answer (score 1):

If the task can have a reference to its parent then that would help in your case.
To get a list of all the tasks you can use `flatMap` or `concatMap`:

```
Observable.just(myJob)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .concatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
                .flatMapIterable(job -> job.getTasks())
                .subscribe(new DefaultObserver<Task>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(@NonNull Task myTask) {
                        Log.d(Utils.APP_LOG,
                                "Total Task: \n " +
                                 "Job id-" + myTask.getJob().getId()
                                 + "tasks-" + myTask);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: This does iterate one by one task object. please read my question. I mentioned list which contains all nested task list per each parent mode. Check @Jon's answer.